# Setting defaults in the 'Select By Attribute' SQL editor

Tags: arcgis-9.3, select-by-attribute

Is there a way to set default values in the 'Select By Attribute' SQL editor (the where clause) ?

I want to set a permanent value that will appear every time I enter the 'Select by Attribute' window, like in this pic:
[image]

It doesn't matter to me if it'll appear in all layers that will be selected or only in specific ones.

Oh, and I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put a definition query on that layer?

Comment: a simple definition query by itself won't help, as it's the same nuisance as having to put the select by attribute string every time. Saying that, I foud 2 ideas enabling me to do a automatic defenition query:                                  (1) http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3841-Change-definition-query-programmatically-for-all-layers-in-mxd                                                          (2) http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit09/papers/pythonscriptingadvancedtechniques.pdf
  NOW I only have to see how to apply that to a SDE...

Answer (score 3):

I think it works as designed. each time you select a new field (even in the same session) the previous query is cleared. best bet is to keep a notepad with favorite queries, and paste those in as you neeed them. there is no need to do anything but paste it into the window and apply.
not much but that is my workaround :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a non-programming way to do this, but you can use the Save and Load buttons at the bottom of the Select by Attributes window to save queries.  I use this functionality for big queries that take some thought to build, but that I do not use very often, and therefore might forget before I need them again.  If it is something that I need to do more than twenty times a day, I write a macro and assign it to one of the F* keys.